# How to pass php array to external js file in WordPress

Tags: php, javascript, array, json

I am trying to pass my php array to my external js file.

PHP

```
 if (!function_exists('myScripts')) {
     function myScripts() {
         wp_enqueue_style('my-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/mycss.css');
         wp_enqueue_script('my-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/myjs.js');

         $fields = get_sub_field('months'); // acf repeater field
         $data = json_encode($fields);

         wp_add_inline_script( 'my-js', 'const dateFields = ' . json_encode( array(
             'ajaxUrl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
             'fields' => $data,
         ) ), 'before' );
     }
     add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myScripts');
 }
```

JS

```
 $(function(){
     console.log(dateFields.fields);
 });
```

If I change:

```
'fields' => $data,
```

to

```
'fields' => 'inline script working'
```

My console log does produce a false initially and "inline script working" successfully so I feel like its the:

```
 $data = json_encode($fields);
```

not working as the $fields variable is passing data to the console when I run a console_log in php

How can I successfully pass my php variable to js